# Dialog manager for Compose dialogs

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-compose, desktop-application

I needed something that would help me keep dialogs in my Jetpack Compose desktop application under control and without dozens of `*Visible` variables etc, so I created the following system.

It's built upon the `DialogManager` class and the `Dialog` interface that dialogs need to implement. It reacts to the changes of the `current` property and shows that dialog when it's not `null`. It also takes care of hiding it by setting that property back to `null`. The two lambdas `dismiss` & `confirm` that are passed to the actual dialog to be called by it are the functions that will handle the answers right at the same location where a dialog was created. This reduces lot's of spagetti calls to other APIs.

```kotlin
interface Dialog<U : Any, T : Any> {
    @Composable
    fun draw(dismiss: (U) -> Unit, confirm: (T) -> Unit)
}

class DialogManager {
    
    private var drawFun by mutableStateOf<(@Composable () -> Unit)?>(null)
    
    fun <U : Any, T : Any> show(
        dialog: Dialog<U, T>,
        onDismiss: (U) -> Unit = {},
        onConfirm: (T) -> Unit
    ) {
        val hide = { drawFun = null }
        drawFun = {
            dialog.draw(
                dismiss = {
                    hide()
                    onDismiss(it)
                },
                confirm = {
                    hide()
                    onConfirm(it)
                }
            )
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun drawDialog() {
        drawFun?.invoke()
    }
}
```

A class implementing the `Dialog` interface is at the same time its model, thus the parameter in the constructor.

```kotlin
class ConfirmDeleteRowsDialog(val rowCount: Int) : Dialog<Unit, Unit> {
    @Composable
    override fun draw(dismiss: (Unit) -> Unit, confirm: (Unit) -> Unit) {
        AlertDialog(
            title = { Text("Delete rows") },
            text = { Text("You are going to delete $rowCount row(s).") },
            confirmButton = {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        confirm(Unit)
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Delete")
                }
            },
            dismissButton = {
                Button(onClick = {
                    dismiss(Unit)
                }
                ) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
            },
            onDismissRequest = { dismiss(Unit) },
        )
    }
}
```

Or using a return value via the `onConfirm` callback when opening a file:

```kotlin
class ImportExcelFileDialog(val parent: Frame? = null) : Dialog<Unit, List<String>> {
    @Composable
    override fun draw(dismiss: (Unit) -> Unit, confirm: (List<String>) -> Unit) {
        AwtWindow(
            create = {
                object : FileDialog(parent, "Pick excel file to import", LOAD) {
                    override fun setVisible(value: Boolean) {
                        super.setVisible(value)
                        if (value) {
                            val excelFiles = files.map { it.absolutePath }.filter { it matches Regex(""".+\.xls(x|m)$""", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE) }
                            confirm(excelFiles)
                        }
                    }
                }.apply {
                    isMultipleMode = true
                }
            },
            dispose = FileDialog::dispose
        )
    }
}
```

I then can easily request a dialog from a `Button` like this:

```kotlin
val dialogManager by remember { DialogManager() }

dialogManager.drawDialog()

Button(
    onClick = {
        model.dialogManager.show(
            ConfirmDeleteRowsDialog(rowCount)
        ) {
            println("Delete!")
        }

    },
) { Text("Delete") }
```

---

What do you think and what would you improve?